# How do I delete Stackoverflow Cookies and certificates in Google Chrome?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, powershell, javascript, cookies

How do I delete Stackoverflow Cookies and certificates in Google Chrome? I am open to using command prompt, or some script to expire all cookies in commandline.

- Want to only delete specific stackoverflow items, not everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete cookies from one website only:

Go in Chrome to `chrome://settings/siteData`, scroll down to the website
and hit the garbage-can icon found to the right of this website.

You may use the right-arrow to drill-down and delete cookies selectively.

Answer (score 1):

To remove cookies in 2024 you want to go:

```
chrome://settings/content/all
```

At this URL, you can remove website-specific cookies:

[image: settings]

---

You can also provide a search parameter. For example, to find stackoverflow cookies, use:

```
chrome://settings/content/all?searchSubpage=stackoverflow
```

---

Then use the trash bin button to delete cookies for that website:
[image: trashbin cookies]